# why the content gets out with 100% width

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Why my `.topnav`, `.mainnav` and my `.content` divs the content escapes them?

How can I make when I reach the page limit jump from line?

They are already 100% width

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 280px 1fr;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.leftbar {
  background: #1D2126;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr;
}

.rightbar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr;
  width: calc(100%-280px);
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 280px;
}

.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 70px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.topnav {
  background: #1A1E23;
}

.mainnav {
  background: #1D2126;
}

.content {
  background: #21252B;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftbar">
    <div class="logo"><img src="https://www.csgoroll.com/en/assets/logo.png" width="80%"></div>
    <div class="chat">
      <div class="chatbox">

      </div>
      <div class="chatsend">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightbar">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="topnav">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
      <div class="mainnav">d</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      asdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaassssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two reasons for that:

First you have an endless text starting "aaaa" so if you don't break the text (with spaces or using CSS) the layout will follow the text

Second  when using the `calc()` function in CSS, using addition and subtraction operations, it is mandatory to leave spaces around the operator, so instead of `width: calc(100%-280px);`
you need to have `width: calc(100% - 280px);`

Look the snippet below (with some minor improvements to your code)

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 280px 1fr;
  height: 100%;
}

.leftbar {
  background: #1D2126;
  height: 100%;
}

.rightbar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr;
}

.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 70px;
}

.topnav {
  background: #1A1E23;
}

.mainnav {
  background: #1D2126;
}

.content {
  background: #21252B;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.logo img {
  width: 80%
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="leftbar">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://www.csgoroll.com/en/assets/logo.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="chat">
        <div class="chatbox">

        </div>
        <div class="chatsend">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightbar">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="topnav">aaaa</div>
        <div class="mainnav">d</div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">aaaa
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```